# Why is Postman crashing right after startup

Tags: google-chrome, crash, postman

Postman is crashing about 5 seconds after starting.  My last operation was a bulk load for ElasticSearch.  The load worked as far as I can tell.  Now Postman crashes.  I have tried restarting several times, but all it does is hang for a few seconds and then crash.

I have Chrome version 56.
Postman version:  4.10.4

Comment: Try downloading the native client, Chrome clients are marked deprecated since Google has dropped support for them.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else is also facing this problem, Postman stores all its data locally in an application-specific indexed DB file. In my case also, the data got bit too large and postman started crashing.Following steps might help, they did in my case:

1. `chrome://indexeddb-internals`
2. Look for: `chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop`
3. Under the "Paths:" section note the location of the `chrome-extension_fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop_0.indexeddb.leveldb` folder
4. Navigate to this location on your local system.
5. Copy this entire contents of this folder and save it to a safe location on your local system to be used later (your collections will be in DB file in this folder)
6. Remove the Postman extension from Chrome and then Re-Add the postman extension.

Postman should open but it will be default settings with none of your collections.

Comment: What guide for the desktop version?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Linux just execute the following command from the terminal and start postman again

```
pkill -fi Postman
```

Comment: Please explain what the command does too, would be really helpful.

Comment: The command `pkill -fi <pattern>` will send a signal to all processes whose full command line matches the specified `<pattern>`. The signal sent by default is SIGTERM, which asks the process to terminate gracefully. 
For example, the command `pkill -fi Postman` will send a SIGTERM signal to all running Postman processes, asking them to close gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Go To:

```
C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Storage\ext\fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\def\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop_0.indexeddb.leveldb\
```

Rename *.log files

And relaunch postman

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted all files from the below folder and launched Postman. Crashing issue is solved. (To be on the safe side, I took a backup of this folder before deleting.)

```
C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Storage\ext\fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\def\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop_0.indexeddb.leveldb
```

Answer (score 0):

**for installed postman application:**

I'm having the exact same issue after trying to log in with Postman on a fresh install. It immediately starts craching. If I remove the cache and config directories of Postman inside the ~/.var/app directory, it will 'work again' until I try to log in again.

for fedora is:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.var/app/com.getpostman.Postman
```

also if that doesnt matter for logging and if you have to use desktop version you need to remove Postman and install them by this [this instruction](https://gist.github.com/Akhil-Suresh/e036a52bd00104ab21e9891224157809)

Answer (score 0):

To solve Postman's longer loading issue follow the below steps:

Uninstall postman.

Delete the Postman folder from the below directories:

-> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local
-> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\

Reinstall the postman.

It will be asked to log in, and login into the web.

All done.